# Sorting/unsorting fields displayed in Identify window of ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, fields-attributes, sorting, identify

I'm using ArcMap 10.1, and upon bringing in a feature class, the identify tool window shows the attributes in alphabetical order of the field headings.

I didn't try to do this and haven't touched any settings.

Is there a way to make them display once again in the order that they were created (as they still are in the att table)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try right clicking the "Field" column header and un-check 'Sort Fields' if it's checked.